# Angular 2 subscribe share items to multiple vars

Tags: angular

I want to share the data to two vars, items and title, how can i achieve that?

```
items = [];
title = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.fetchData(this.id)
        .subscribe(
        (data) => this.items = data,
        (error) => handleError(error),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.fetchData(this.id)
        .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.items = data;
          this.title = data;
        },
        (error) => handleError(error),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
this.dataService.fetchData(this.id)
  .subscribe(
    (data) => this.items = this.title = data,
    (error) => handleError(error),
);
```